# (C#) Detect type of Windows OS (non-localized)

Tags: c#, windows

I need to detect what type (*edition*) of Windows OS is installed. By type I mean, for example: "Home", "Enterprise" or "Professional". Please don't ask why (I've already had that uphill-struggle with the requirement-wizards).

Right now the problem is that the Windows types seem to be localized, and I need a way to use them in a switch statement to do different behavior.

Right now I do this:

```
_os = (from x in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem").Get().OfType<ManagementObject>()
       select x.GetPropertyValue("Caption")).First().ToString().Trim();
switch (_os)
{   
    case "Microsoft Windows XP Professional":
        {
            // Do professional stuff...
            break;
        }
    case "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional":
    case "Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate":
    case "Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise":
        {
            // Do ultimate enterprisey professional stuff
            break;
        }
    default:
        {
            // File not found
            break;
        }
}
```

Anyone know how this could be done to not run into the issue of localization?

Comment: Did you look here? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73000/Getting-Operating-System-Version-Info-Even-for-Win

Comment: I'd say it's not an exact duplicate (although I *had* missed that question), because the answers there include just getting the value -- but it may be localized, which I want to avoid and is my focus of this question.

Answer (score 0):

On Codeproject is a nice article (with dll) to do this:

[Getting Operating System Version Info - Even for Windows 8!](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73000/Getting-Operating-System-Version-Info-Even-for-Win)

He get's his cheese from:

[Determine Windows Version and Edition with C#](http://www.csharp411.com/determine-windows-version-and-edition-with-c/)

Answer (score 0):

See `OperatingSystemSKU` property in [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class, this is `uint`-based enumeration.

Comment: This is good, but does not work on Windows XP.

Comment: @AmadeusHein: for XP, see `OSProductSuite` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can P/Invoke the [GetProductInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) native API. Usage and example in C# [can be found here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getproductinfo)

Though its only supported in Vista and above.

Here is [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724429.aspx) of how its done in C++ which can be easily P/Invoked

For XP, I don't think there is any way to get this info in a non-localized way I'm afraid.